# Join Table From Minimum Value and Specific Name

Tags: sql, join

I have:

Table id

> ```
> +--------+
> | number |
> +--------+
> |      1 |
> |      2 |
> |      3 |
> +--------+
> ```

Table data

> ```
> +-------+--------------+
> | name  | phone_number |
> +-------+--------------+
> | Bob   |          111 |
> | John  |          333 |
> | Alice |          555 |
> +-------+--------------+
> ```

How to join table with results: (number from minimum value & name='John') ?

```
+--------+-------+--------------+
| number | name  | phone_number |
+--------+-------+--------------+
|      1 | John  |          333 |
+--------+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
   select
        (select min(number) FROM ID) as number, name, phone_number
    from date 
    where name = 'John'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join`:

```
select min(number) as number, name, phone_number
from Table_Id
cross join Table_Data
group by name, phone_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the RDBMS you're using, this query should get you close.

```
SELECT 
    MIN_NUMBER, NAME, PHONE_NUMBER
FROM
    DATA LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(NUMBER) AS MIN_NUMBER FROM ID) ON 1=1
WHERE NAME = 'JOHN'
```